# Exposing another port for Nginx in DockerFile

Tags: docker, port, nginx, expose

I'm new to DockerFile.
I want Nginx to be listening on port `8080`. so I've written the dockerFile in this way:

```
FROM nginx:1.11-alpine
COPY index.html /usr/share/nginx/html
EXPOSE 8080
CMD ["nginx", "-g" , "daemon off;"]
```

but after making image and running container with this command:

```
docker run -d -p 80:8080 nginxt:v3
```

and Curl on localhost I'm getting this error :

```
curl: (56) Recv failure: Connection reset by peer
```

what am I doing wrong? EXPOSE 8080 doesn't mean that Nginx must be listened on 8080?

Answer (score 3):

By defining `EXPOSE 8080` on your Dockerfile, you are only changing the [exposed container port](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#expose), but your Nginx server will still listen on port 80 (as it is configured by default).

**You need to change the Nginx [`listen`](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#listen) configuration to match your new exposed port**.

*Different from mostly docker implementations, Nginx doesn't support such configs by using environment variables (see [Using environment variables in Nginx configuration](https://hub.docker.com/_/nginx) on their Docker Hub page).*

If you wish to adapt the Nginx default configuration, you need to create a new `nginx.conf` with the `listen 8080;` config, then replace the original using `COPY` in your Dockerfile.

If your prefer an "one-line workaround", you can change the command to replace the config on every start:

```
FROM nginx:1.11-alpine
COPY index.html /usr/share/nginx/html
EXPOSE 8080
CMD ["/bin/sh", "-c", "sed -i 's/listen  .*/listen 8080;/g' /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf && exec nginx -g 'daemon off;'"]
```

---

### Update

**Since version 1.19** Docker image Nginx will extract environment variables before it starts:

> By default, this function reads template files in
> `/etc/nginx/templates/*.template` and outputs the result of executing
> `envsubst to /etc/nginx/conf.d.`
>
> So if you place `templates/default.conf.template` file, which contains
> variable references like this:
>
> `listen       ${NGINX_PORT};`
>
> outputs to `/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf` like this:
>
> `listen       80;`